# Generate C# test cases automatically while recording the screen in UFT (Unified Functional Testing)

Tags: c#, hp-uft, uft14

Using `HPE UFT`, we can record the UI actions and generate the VBScripts automatically.

- Is there a way, that I can generate the `C#` code for the UI
  interaction with the same auto generate option?
- Is that possible in `UFT`?

Please advice. Thanks.

Note:  I am experienced in C# and have zero knowledge in VBScript.

Comment: While this is probably possible I doubt there´s any framework that does it for your. Even *if* it were Stack isn´t the right place to ask for libraries or howtos but rather for specific programming-related questions showing a particular problem and your affords you´ve done.

Answer (score 2):

[LeanFT](https://saas.hpe.com/en-us/software/leanft) is the tool in HPE's functional testing family that supports C#<sup>1</sup>, currently<sup>2</sup> it does not support recording but a quick search found a (non-HPE) product that [converts UFT to LeanFT](http://www.cigniti.com/uft-leanft-migration-accelerator).

Footnotes:

1. as well as Java and JavaScript
2. True as of May 2017, I expect this will change in the future

Comment: In my case, my client has already purchased the UFT. So before starting, I need to make sure that whether UFT supports C# or not? If it doesn't I will have to learn VBScript. I had asked the same in HPE community forum as well. I haven't received any updates yet.

Comment: The GUI-testing part of UFT (which you are using) only works with VBScript. However depending on the license of UFT you client has purchased you may be entitled to use LeanFT too. (UFT also has an API-testing part which uses C# but it's not relevant for this case)

Comment: Thanks much for the information. Can you please explain it a bit more? Which licensed version supports using LeanFT? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's the documentation I found http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/UFTLic_LicenseCategories.htm

Comment: Thanks, Have you ever used UFT? Are you sure that with the UFT, we can't auto generate the cases in C#? I mean, have you ever read any post s which mention it? It would be great if you can share me that as well, so that I can share the same with my client. Once again thank for your help.

Comment: @SibeeshVenu, [I've worked with UFT](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/hp-uft/topusers) and I can guarantee that it only supports VBScript for its tests

Comment: That's great. Does LeanFT supports the auto generation of code( While recording the UI)? Do you have any idea on that?